# How to run a BigQuery query and then send the output CSV to Google Cloud Storage in Apache Airflow?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

I need to run a bigquery script in python, which needs to output as a CSV in google cloud storage. Currently, my script triggers the big query code and saves to my PC directly.

However, I need to get this running in Airflow so I can't have any local dependencies.

My current script saves the output to my local machine and then I have to move it into GCS. Looked online and I can't figure it out. (ps im very new to python so im sorry in advance if this has been asked before!)

````
import pandas as pd
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

def run_script():

    df = pd.read_gbq('SELECT * FROM `table/veiw` LIMIT 15000',
                 project_id='PROJECT',
                 dialect='standard'
                 )

    df.to_csv('XXX.csv', index=False)

def copy_to_gcs(filename, bucket, destination_filename):

    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    body = {'name': destination_filename}
    req = service.objects().insert(bucket=bucket,body=body, media_body=filename)
    resp = req.execute()

current_date = datetime.date.today()
filename = (r"C:\Users\LOCALDRIVE\ETC\ETC\ETC.csv")
bucket = 'My GCS BUCKET'

str_prefix_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
destfile = 'XXX' + str_prefix_datetime + '.csv'
print('')

    ```
````

Comment: I would recommend to just use the [BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_gcs.html). Also, take into account that you are [not charged](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#pricing) for exports.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Airflow provides several operators for working with BigQuery.

- [BigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator) executes queries on BigQuery.
- [BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_gcs/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_to_gcs.BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator) exports a BigQuery table (such as the destination table of a query) to GCS.

You can see an example of running a query, followed by [exporting the results to a CSV in the Cloud Composer code samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/c311bc36ccefc7629a4008a780d04e308ac5447d/composer/workflows/bq_notify.py#L98-L119).

```
# Copyright 2018 Google LLC
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# Query recent StackOverflow questions.

bq_recent_questions_query = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='bq_recent_questions_query',
    sql="""
    SELECT owner_display_name, title, view_count
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
    WHERE creation_date < CAST('{max_date}' AS TIMESTAMP)
        AND creation_date >= CAST('{min_date}' AS TIMESTAMP)
    ORDER BY view_count DESC
    LIMIT 100
    """.format(max_date=max_query_date, min_date=min_query_date),
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    destination_dataset_table=bq_recent_questions_table_id)

# Export query result to Cloud Storage.
export_questions_to_gcs = bigquery_to_gcs.BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='export_recent_questions_to_gcs',
    source_project_dataset_table=bq_recent_questions_table_id,
    destination_cloud_storage_uris=[output_file],
    export_format='CSV')
```

Comment: great answer, But if the the table size is more than 1 GB The Airflow operator will throw you an error .How would you handle this incase of table size is more than 1 GB?.Thanks in Advance

Comment: @sethu That might be a good candidate for another question. Please include the error that Airflow throws.

Comment: Hello Tim Swast Thanks for your instant reply.
 I am using bq_to_gcs operator to pull the bigquery table data to gcs and table size is more then 1 GB and Airflow giving an error like as shown below
"BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Table dataset_reference {\n project_reference {\n project_id:*******\n gaia_id: *******\n }\n dataset_id: *******\n dataset_uuid: ****\n}\ntable_id: ****\ntable_uuid: ******* too large to be exported to a single file. Specify a uri including a * to shard export. "

Comment: You're right that BigQuery limits CSV output file size to 1GB per file, but you can specify a filename template for an extract job by including a `*` character in the filename. BQ will expand `*` to a page indicator such as `000000000001`. See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files

Comment: Thanks Again. But is that doable with the Airflow bq_to_gcs Operator?

Comment: I don't think it is still applicable in Airflow 2.