# Sending bigquery data by email -airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a project in BQ that consists of sending reports in csv format on a daily basis.
These reports are the results of queries to bigquery which are then compressed to csv and mailed.

Use the implementation of the following question to solve my problem.
[How to run a BigQuery query and then send the output CSV to Google Cloud Storage in Apache Airflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456094/how-to-run-a-bigquery-query-and-then-send-the-output-csv-to-google-cloud-storage)
[image]

Now, I am trying to change that implementation.

the reason is because:

1. the main reason is because I don't like the idea of ​​creating temporary tables to export the result. I have not found an operator that exports the result of a query.
2. I don't need to take the data to storage, especially if I'm going to download it to the local airflow directory anyway.

Try using "get_pandas_df" from
bigquery_hook and then pass the result through xcom to another task that will be in charge of compressing to csv. Due to the heavyness of the Dataframe it was not possible.

Do you have any idea how to do it directly?

Answer (score 2):

In Airflow it is equally easy to use existing operators as well as write your own operators. This is all Python. Airflow has two-layered approach for external services - it has Operators (where each operators does a single operation) and Hooks (which is a super-easy to use interface providing API to communicate with external services.

In your case rather than composing the existing operators, you should rather create your own operator by using multiple hooks. One Hook to read the data to pandas frame for example, then a bit of Python code to extract the data in a form that you can attach to the mail and then use 'send_email' from util to send the email (there is no separate Hook for sending email because sending emails is a standard feature of Airflow Core as well). You can take a look at the EmailOperator code to see how send_email is used and also BigQueryOperators on how to use BigQueryHook.

You can do it in two ways:

1. Classic - define your own operator as object (you can do it in youd DAG file and use it in your DAG).

```
class MyOperator(BaseOperator):
     __init__.....
     def execute():
          bq_hook = BigQueryHook(.....)
          ... do stuff ...
          send_email(....)
```

2. Task Flow API (which is much more Pythonic/functional and less boilerplate):

```
@dag(...)
def my_dag():
    @task()
    def read_data_and_send_email():
          bq_hook = BigQueryHook(.....)
          ... do stuff ...
          send_email(....)
```

Task flow is I think better for your needs: see http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html