# Run a BigQuery query and write the data into cloud storage bucket in parquet using airflow

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to create a DAG which will pull data from a BigQuery query and write into a gcs bucket in parquet format. I looked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456094/how-to-run-a-bigquery-query-and-then-send-the-output-csv-to-google-cloud-storage) and got some help here. It suggest using `BigQueryOperator` to execute queries and then write into gcs bucket using `BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator`. With this approach, I will have to first write the result of a query in a table and from that table, I will write in gcs bucket.

It will be 2 steps as below:

```
bq_query = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='bq_query',
    sql="""
        <select query with filters>
        """.format(date=date1),
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        destination_dataset_table=<table_name>
        location="southamerica-east1",
        write_disposition="WRITE_EMPTY",
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED")



export_to_gcs = bigquery_to_gcs.BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='export_to_gcs',
    source_project_dataset_table=destination_dataset_table,
    destination_cloud_storage_uris=[output_file],
    export_format='PARQUET')
```

Is there a way where I can directly write the big query data into gcs bucket without having it write to a table first? I believe direct export is possible but what I am looking at running a query with filters and then writing to gcs.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, operators provide us with a fixed way to do things and its not always optimal but it saves time. So, one of the approach will be to have a python operator which have a function that retrieves bigquery data and uploads the output to storage.

PythonOperator

```
task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_data_and_upload',
        python_callable=get_bigquery_data,
        op_kwargs={'custom_date': date}
      )
```

function get_bigquery_data

```
# Libraries to use 
from google.cloud import bigquery, storage 
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas as pd

# function
def get_data_and_upload(custom_date):
    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    key_path = "path/to/service_account.json"

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        key_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
    )

    client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, 
    project=credentials.project_id,)
    
    #for this sample im just print it and not using it.
    print(custom_date)

    query = """
        SELECT name, SUM(number) as total_people
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
        WHERE state = 'TX'
        GROUP BY name, state
        ORDER BY total_people DESC
        LIMIT 20
    """
    query_job = client.query(query)  
    output = []

    # build our result object
    for row in query_job:
        output.append({'name':row[0],'total_people':row[1]})

    # move to a dataframe. I use pandas for parquet conversion
    df = pd.DataFrame(output)
    bobject = df.to_parquet(path=None,compression='gzip')

    # upload file object to google cloud storage
    bucket_name = "my-bucket-name" 
    destination_blob_name = "parquet_files/parquet_file.gzip" 

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_string(bobject) 

    print("File uploaded to {}.".format(destination_blob_name))
```

Also, above sample is all just done in a single step. it works but its not usual nice to see, too rigid. Remember, you can create python functions ( one for getting the data, one for transforming the data and the one that push it into the actual storage ) as you see fit. If your airflow version is above 2.0, you can use `taskflowapi` to pass parameters. If you version is below that version you will have to use `XCOM`.

I have tested the function, I think you should be careful translating this into your airflow installation due to your own environment limitations or versioning as you may need to update the code or use different libraries to get the same output.

Other options is to create your own [custom operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#creating-a-custom-operator).

Here are some useful links:

- [Python Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html)
- [Passing parameters between operators using taskflowapi](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python)
- [Bigquery Python Client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries)
- [Bigquery authentication](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file)
- [Pandas to_parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html)
- [Uploading a file using Cloud Storage Python Client](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python)